# Array of pointers to dynamic arrays: how to access without variable name

Tags: c++, arrays, oop, pointers, object

I have a problem with an assignment I'm working on at the moment.

Essentially, I have a static array containing object pointers. I want these pointers to each point to a dynamic array. I'm not sure how I would have individual variable names for each individual dynamic array, since this function works on adding one object at a time to one of the dynamic array.

Here is my static array.

```
Profile *myelements[26];  //Profile is my class
```

From here, how can I point to an array at each index? I would use a loop, but then each object would have the same name, wouldn't it?

For example. I am trying to insert a new object of class Profile into index 0 of myelement. Could I do something like this? I am not sure about the syntax.

```
myelements[index]=new Profile[1]; //am I allowed to create an object without a variable name like this??
Profile[0] = newElement  //newElement is the object I want to insert
```

Comment: I don't get it - why can't you use `myelements[0]`, `myelements[1]`, and so on? (Or `myelements[blah]` where `blah` is some variable)

Comment: @immibis Because myelements is my static array, not the dynamic arrays I want to create and access.

Comment: `myelements` is your static array. And `myelements[whatever]` is one of the elements of your static array. So `myelements[whatever]` is one of the dynamic arrays you want to create and access, no?

Comment: @immibis yes, that is correct. But how do I insert or remove things  from this dynamic array now that I see it? How do I access it?

Comment: How do you access a dynamic array called `abc`? Now how do you access a dynamic array called `myelements[5]`?

Answer (score 2):

> how can I point to an array at each index? I would use a loop...

Here's how you access to an array at each index in a loop as follows:

```
// Let's just say you have Profile like this.
struct Profile
{
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

Now you can write to create / access to elements of `myelements` as follows:

```
Profile * myelements[24];

for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
{
    // Create elements.
    myelements[i] = new Profile{ 10, 20 };
}

for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
{
    // Access to elemetns.
    cout << myelements[i]->a << endl;
    cout << myelements[i]->b << endl;
}
```

**EDIT:**

You can insert an existing object to an array as an element as follows:

```
// Insert an existing object as an element.
Profile new_profile_object { 1, 2 };
myelements[0] = &new_profile_object;

cout << myelements[0]->a << endl;
cout << myelements[0]->b << endl;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. What if I am trying to insert an array of object Profile into each index position of myelements? For example. I am trying to insert a new object of class Profile into index 0 of myelement. Could I do something like this? I am not sure about the syntax.

myelements[index]=new Profile[1]; //am I allowed to create an object without a variable name like this??
Profile[0] = newElement  //newElement is the object I want to insert

Comment: @JennySo Please read my edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Dean's answer is correct, so I'll try to be as detailed as possible.

Given an static array, you want to create a dynamic array on each place, so I think you want to create something like a **matrix**.

Then, you have:

```
Profile *myelements[26];
```

The variable myelements is an **array of pointers** to Persona (and pointer can be used as arrays in C++).

So we want to create a dynamic array on each index:

```
void create dynamic_array(int index, int size) {
    // creates a dynamic array of size "size" at the index "index"
    myElements[index] = new Profile[size];

    // now i will set some variables on each of the elements of the array
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        myElements[index][i].a = 0; // Using definition from Dean's answer
        myElements[index][i].b = 0; // Using definition from Dean's answer
    }
}
```

I think what you are looking for is the following statement:

```
myElements[index][i]
```

The code above allows to acces the object at the position `i` of the array located at the position `index`of the array `myElements`.

**Note:**

Consider the following code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 24; i++)
{
    // Create elements.
    myelements[i] = new Profile{ 10, 20 };
}
```

That code initializes each element on the static array, but does not create a dynamic array inside the other one, it just allocates a pointer.